# Optional character in bash regex

Tags: regex, bash

How do I specify a character as optional? e.g. a filename could have 3 or 4 digits, so the 4th is optional: `filename-123.txt` & `filename-4567.txt`. Currently I'm just doing this with 2 commands with `find -name`: *-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].* and *-[0-9][0-9][0-9].*. How do I do this with 1?

Edit: I am now using find -regex, `find ./src/static/images/ -regex '^.*-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]?\..*' -print` as explained in the linked source (marked as a possible duplicate solution) which still doesn't work for me.

Comment: the duplicate answer doesn't work for me, ```find ./src/static/images/ -regex "^*-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]?.*" -print```

Comment: I changed the duplicate source. Do not re-ask the same question.

Comment: okay thanks for the new suggestion but unfortunately still doesn't work, ```find ./src/static/images/ -regex '.*resp-.*-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\..*' -print``` prints all the files with 4 numbers, but ```find ./src/static/images/ -regex '.*resp-.*-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]?\..*' -print``` prints none

Comment: Note that making that 4th digit matching pattern optional is the same as if you just removed it because `.*` will match any char after 3 or 4 digits. You may use `'.*resp-.*-[0-9][0-9][0-9].*'` and it will work as expected. Another point, you may try `\?`, or `\{0,1\}`. Also, why use three `[0-9]`? Try `{3,4}` or `\{3,4\}`.

Comment: ah yes, sorry I have updated my question to include a dot afterwards (the wildcard at the end is just suppose to denote any file extensio)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Oh it was the backslashes I needed! I was using{3,4} before but that wasn't working for the same reason. Thanks very much for your help :)

Comment: The reason is that by default, the BRE POSIX engine is used. And there, you need to escape the quantifiers.